# setting permissions on folders created through group policy

Tags: group-policy, windows-server-2012

I have a domain controller running server 2012 std. In the *default domain policy* I set up a *folder* in *User Configuration>Windows Settings>Folders* The path is **\\MyServer\MyShare\%USERNAME%**

This works well. Any user that logs in gets a folder on the server the same as their user name. I'm also automatically mapping to that folder. What I can't figure out is how to set each folder so that only that user (and the admin) has access to it. Is this possible through Group Policy?

Comment: Just as a side note: you really want to modify the default domain policy as little as possible. Instead, create a new GPO and link it at the domain level.

Comment: Yes, my final will do just that. I'm just testing on a GPO already applied to everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following article details how to set the Share and NTFS permissions for folder redirection. The same should be applicable to what you're doing. The article was written for Windows Server 2003 but should be applicable to any share, regardless of host OS.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781907(v=ws.10).aspx